# How to backup whole table into a single field item?

Tags: postgresql

I have few very small tables (a total of ~1000 rows) that I want to backup regularly into the same DB, to a single table. I know it sounds weird but hear me out.

Let's say that the tables I want to backup are named `linux_commands`, and `windows_commands`. These two tables have roughly: `id (pkey), name, definition, config (jsonb), commands`.

I want to back these up everyday into a table called `commands_backup` and I want this new table to have a date field, a field for `windows_commands`, and another one for `linux_commands`, so three columns in total. Each day, a script would run and write current date to date field, and then fetch whole `linux_commands` table and write it to related field in a single row, then do the same for `windows_commands`.

How would you setup something like this? Also, what is the best data type for storing whole data set in a single item?

Answer (score 1):

In the target table, `windows_commands` and `linux_commands` should be type `jsonb`.

Then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO commands_backup VALUES (
   current_date,
   (SELECT jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(linux_commands)) FROM linux_commands),
   (SELECT jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(windows_commands)) FROM windows_commands)
);
```